# Updating a list within a loop by applying a function

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to write a simple loop in Python. Here's the code:

```
N = 1000

xrange = np.arange(-1.0,0.0,1.0/N)
drange = 1.0 + xrange
yrange = np.zeros(N)

range = np.arange(0,N,1)

for i in range:
    if drange[i] == 1.0:
        yrange[i] == 1.0
    else:
        yrange[i] == np.log(drange[i])/(drange[i] - 1.0)

print(yrange)
```

However after the `for` loop has run, the list `yrange` doesn't get updated. It still has all values at zero.

Is there anything wrong with the `else:` part of the loop?

Comment: `==` is comparison, not assignment.

Comment: Your loop is not nested.

Comment: @abarnert Right. Thanks for putting out the mistake.

Comment: @DYZ I'm new to coding, and I code on a on and off basis. I just realized the mistake in using the terminology. Within the for loop, I am just running through the loop by applying some conditional statements. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Also, `range` is a reserved word.  Don't clobber it with the assignment `range = np.arange(0,N,1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your first error is using `==` instead of `=` for the assignment, as mentioned by @abarnert in the comments. Your second error is using a loop instead of the NumPy vectorized operations. Your code ideally should look like this:

```
N = 1000

drange = np.arange(-1.0, 0.0, 1.0 / N)
yrange = np.where(drange == 0.0, 1.0, np.log(drange + 1) / drange)

print(yrange)
```

Finally, the condition `drange == 0.0` is never true because of the rounding errors, but hopefully, this is not important.

Comment: True. The whole purpose of the problem trying to solve that due to rounding off errors, the expression 1 + x may be equal to x if the value of x is so small that it underflows the range of values allowed. When I’ll make x very small, this rounding off error would kick in. The question I’m trying to solve argues that such a code would take care of that problem once x becomes arbitrarily close to zero. That’s what I’ll get to after getting this code to run.